# Code execution time in c# for time taking function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having code for upload  , which is running fine 
I am uploading bulk data which is taking long time  ,
So once I start my operation I need to wait for random time
I need to calculate how much time my code required to complete operation 
because I am going to execute same code again and again

Comment: Please better specify what code do you have and what exactly do you want to measure.

Comment: You could use a stopwatch instance and print to console, file, etc. you could also use a progress bar to give you some sort of idea as to the progression of the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// your code which will be get measured
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Duplicate question you will get lot more answer even if you go through stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the time you can use a Stopwatch:

```
// Create new stopwatch.
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing.
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something.

// Stop timing.
stopwatch.Stop();

// Write result.
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```